# Relationship of eigenvalue/eigenvector of hermitian matrix R and QRQ (Q is diagonal)

Tags: matrices, eigenvector, eigenvalues, hermitian

For a hermitian matrix R and a diagonal one Q, is there any relationship between eigenvalues/eigenvectors of R and QRQ?

To be specific, assuming the eigenvalue decomposition of R is R=VDV*, then can the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of QRQ be represented by V, D & Q?

Thanks a lot!

*In fact I've ask [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682232/relationship-of-eigenvalue-eigenvector-of-hermitian-matrix-r-and-qrq-q-is-diago/682297?noredirect=1#comment1445742_682297) on math.stackexchange already, and was advocated to ask here. I do hope to get a proof for it.*

Comment: No, there's no nice relation unless $Q$ and $R$ are in a special position with respect to each other.

Comment: Hi, Alex!
What do you mean by saying "Q and R are in a special position with respect to each other"?

Comment: I mean that $R$ is also diagonal. (In the learned language, $Q$ and $R$ commute, or are simultaneously diagonalizable.)

Comment: Q is diagonal; R is hermitian, so it's diagonalizable. Then conditions satisfied?

Comment: **Simultaneously** diagonalizable. Otherwise, there's no hope to see what $Q$ does to the eigenvectors of $R$.

Comment: Not sure if you call that a "relationship", but if the diagonal is real the signature of the matrix is preserved, so you can at least predict their signs. I.e., $R$ and $QRQ$ have the same number of positive, zero, and negative eigenvalues. That's probably all that you can get.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, can you cross-link to the math.se question, just for reference?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Federico! I've modified the question to link the one on math.se.

By the way, I'm wondering why there're so many minuses here :(

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments. However, there is a special case of interest, more general than commutation. Assume $R$ is a positive definite Hermitian matrix: this means that we can find a matrix $V$ such that
$$
R=VDV^*,\quad V^*V=I,\quad\text{$D$ diagonal positive.}
$$
Now if $S$ is another Hermitian matrix, the matrix $V^*SV$ is also Hermitian as well as 
$D^{-1/2}V^*SVD^{-1/2}$. Thus we can find $W$ such that
$$
W^*D^{-1/2}V^*SVD^{-1/2}W=\Delta,\quad W^*W=I,\quad\text{$\Delta$ diagonal.}
$$
We have thus
$$
S=V D^{1/2}W\Delta W^* D^{1/2}V^*,\quad
R=VDV^*=VD^{1/2}WW^*D^{1/2}V^*
$$
which means that the $\boxed{\text{quadratic forms } R,S}$  are simultaneously diagonalizable: with the invertible matrix $P=W^*D^{1/2}V^*$, we have
$$
\langle Rx,x\rangle=\langle P^*Px,x\rangle=\Vert Px\Vert^2,\quad
\langle Sx,x\rangle=\langle P^*\Delta Px,x\rangle=\langle \Delta Px,Px\rangle,\quad\text{with $\Delta$ diagonal.}
$$
In particular, if $(e_j)_{1\le j\le n}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$,
$(f_j=P^{-1}e_j)_{1\le j\le n}$
is also a basis and for 
$x=\sum_j x_j f_j$, we have
$$
\langle Rx,x\rangle=\sum_j x_j^2,\quad \langle Sx,x\rangle=\sum_j \Delta_j x_j^2,\quad \Delta=\text{diag}(\Delta_1,\dots,\Delta_n).
$$

Comment: I do appreciate your analysis, Bazin!